Communicate with UNIX sockets opened by dbus-daemon
I'm trying to learn how to interact with message buses under Linux, and doing so with shell commands that doesn't involve utilities packaged under dbus-*. For this instance, I want to understand how socket opened by dbus-daemon are interpreted, and how the socket behaves in response to some user input. (e.g, send commands and receive a response output)
For the "reference implementation", namely dbus-daemon, looking at its user configuration file (session.conf) under /usr/share/dbus-1, the daemon opens an UNIX domain socket and listens on in based on transport names and subsequent options in the <listen> directive. By default, it is set to the transport name unix with a tmpdir set to /tmp. Modifying the line with path in place of tmpdir to where the socket must reside in disk, a socket file by the respective path is created by running dbus-deamon as:
$ sudo dbus-daemon --session

By querying lsof to list open sockets
sudo lsof -c dbus-daemon -aU -a +E

it indeed lists the path that was written on the configuration file. Now, I want to interact with the socket by sending it some data and inspecting its response. So far, I've tried netcat and socat.
$ echo <some_txt> | nc -U /tmp/socket -v
$ echo <some_txt> | socat - /tmp/socket
2024/12/12 22:55:47 socat[21493] E read(5, 0x61fb9e544000, 8192): Connection reset by peer

While netcat returns with nothing, I get a "connection reset by peer" error from socat when "<some_txt>" is being piped out and it is a string of words. Instead, if the input is a newline or a blank, socat exits successfully (however with no output). It makes me suspect a formatting problem of the input that the socket may accept.
I also tried configuring the daemon to open a TCP connection in the loopback address on port randomized by the kernel by setting port=0 (as mentioned in the manpage). Going by the output of lsof, I resolved the port which it's listening on.
$ echo <some_txt> | nc localhost 39231
nc: connect to localhost (::1) port 39231 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 39231 port [tcp/*] succeeded!


Returns with connection refused.
It would be of help if anyone can explain:

The command interface for interacting with listening sockets
The right approach to send data to the socket
If it's possible to get a reply from the socket.



While netcat returns with nothing, I get a "connection reset by peer" error from socat when "<some_txt>" is being piped out and it is a string of words. Instead, if the input is a newline or a blank, socat exits successfully (however with no output). It makes me suspect a formatting problem of the input that the socket may accept.

The service is closing your connection because it received what it perceives as a malformed message. D-Bus is not a text-based protocol like you seem to expect – it uses a binary format (much like C structs) where individual text fields do exist but only in between various other non-text fields. The specification has all the details.
(And for that matter, it doesn't really have "commands" as such; everything in D-Bus revolves around messages, so there's no "SEND" or "HELP" command in the protocol like there would be with SMTP or IRC – instead programs directly write messages through the connection, and receive messages back. Even internal dbus-daemon control functions are accessed in-band by sending a message to a special destination address, rather than out-of-band commands.)
So you really need to use a D-Bus client for communicating with dbus-daemon; for example, busctl or gdbus call or dbus-send. (All of them can be told to use a TCP connection in case you want to see the traffic in Wireshark or tcpdump – although running any D-Bus client under strace could already show you what it sends and receives even for Unix sockets.)
